# Heroku error - We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running on rails 3.2.7. I get the following message on deployed app:
**We're sorry, but something went wrong.**

I really don't have any idea what could cause this mistake.

This is are my heroku logs.

```
2012-10-10T20:24:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-10-10T21:28:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2012-10-10T21:28:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-10-10T21:28:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-10-10T21:28:21+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-10-10 21:28:21] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-10-10T21:28:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-10-10T21:28:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-10-10T21:28:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-10-10T21:28:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-10-11T17:24:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2012-10-11T17:24:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-10-11T17:24:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-10-11T17:24:28+00:00 heroku[router]: GET mighty-earth-4316.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=0
pj@ubuntu:~/Documents/demotywatory$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.7
```

and gemfile

## Gemfile.rb

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'nifty-generators'
  gem 'simple_form'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem "bootstrap-will_paginate"
end

gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'thumbs_up'
gem 'devise'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'


# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

Comment: At which point you 're getting this message? Right after a `git push`? Can you try a `heroku restart` and see what happens? Do you receive any other errors besides this?

Comment: Just to double-check: do you need to run "heroku rake db:migrate"? I usually forget to do that. Another thing to check is "heroku run console" and you should get a better stack dump describing the error.

Comment: I already run heroku run rake db:migrate

Comment: I get this message right after git push. I just tried heroku restart and it's not working.

Comment: In your Terminal, run `heroku logs --tail`, clear the screen (Command K, if you're on a Mac), then access your site to reproduce the error. If the new logging doesn't help you see the problem, then please include it in an update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

try taking haml out of the assets group. After wrangling around with trying to figure out what was going wrong with my DB, taking haml out of the assets group in my gemfile fixed it for me.